# Using term query with Or operator

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to use the term query the following way!!

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "technology": "Space"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "Person": "Steve Simon"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Which returns me a response of feeds which has both fields present in single feed like an intersection operation. Can I use the term query to get UNION result for the above query like, I want all feeds which has `space`, `Steve Simon` present individually with feeds which has both present.

Answer (score 11):

Use `should` instead of `must`. Also you have to set `minimum_should_match` to 1 which means that only one `should` clause is needed for matching a document.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "technology": "Space"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "Person": "Steve Simon"
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  }
}
```